# Using jQuery to create default list item on page load

Tags: jquery, css

I realize this has probably been answered before but I am a designer just getting my feet wet with jQuery. I have scoured the forums and for some reason or another cannot get this to work. I need the first item in my list to be focused on the page load and then unfocused as other items are clicked on.Can anyone help an illiterate javascript/jQuery coder?

Here is my code:

html

```
<ul class="menuleft">
    <li id="children"><a href="#">children</a></li>
    <li id="mascots"><a href="#">mascots</a></li>
    <li id="corporate"><a href="#">corporate</a></li>
    <li id="books"><a href="#">books</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#children").focus();
    });
</script>
```

CSS

```
.sidebar ul.menuleft a {
    display: inline;
    color: #89300e;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0px 24px 4px 14px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #3C352C;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: rgba(229,223,168,0.3);
    border: 1px solid #9F6B02;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px 3px rgba(69,40,2,0.5);
    -webkit-transition: all linear .1s .1s;
    transition: all linear .1s .1s;
}
.sidebar ul.menuleft li:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0em;
}

.sidebar ul.menuleft a:hover, .sidebar ul.menuleft a:focus {
    color: #f4c874;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #f4c874;
    outline: 0;
    background-color: rgba(109,62,2,0.6);
    border: 1px solid #6a3a00;
}
```

Comment: You are setting focus on the containing <LI> element with id children and your css is for a:focus - try setting the focus on the anchor element

Comment: Just FYI: if you target modern browsers (IE>9) you don't need jQuery for that, just add "autofocus" attribute to the first link.
`<li id="children"><a href="#" autofocus>children</a></li>`

Answer (score 1):

You want the `a` tag to be focused, not the `li`

```
$("#children a").focus();
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix tymeJV, that worked, I knew it was something simple. Much appreciated